# Doctrine Query builder count of related

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

Lets say I have a typical forum setup (posts, comments, users) with bidirectional relationships

Snippet from my post repository

```
Builder('post')
            ->innerJoin('post.user', 'user')
            ->addSelect('user')
            //->innerJoin('post.comment', 'comment')
            ->setMaxResults(25)
```

This is what I have.  I'm passing the result to twig in Symfony 3.  I can use post.user and the other related post fields.

I need to be able to get the total replies/comments and the date of the most recent comment.

I could do it in SQL but I'm struggling with the query builder.
I'm not opposed to just using sql/dql but If I always fall back to sql I'll never get a decent grasp on the builder.

Since I'm a newbie even pointing me to what to google could help  as my google fu is failing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isnt the use case for the query builder. I ended up writing dql to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$count = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->join('p.comments', 'c')
            ->select('count(c.id)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: My apologies my post was not worded precisely enough. Having the total number of all comments period isn't what I'm trying to do. Its the total comments for *each post*.

Comment: In sql I'd just join my posts table to a subquery that adds a count and a max(date) from comments and the result would have all of the info I need about the post, and the number of replies, and the most recent post.

Comment: Ok, got you. Well than i would suggest you to split this on separate queries. Because i am pretty sure it is not possible with query builder.

Otherwise if you do not want to do that - native sql is the way.